# Amazon CloudFront key-pair creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

From my "Security Credentials", I can NOT create any more key pairs for my CloudFront setup.
I can only see my existing 2 key pairs and my deleted one. The "create" link is not present.
Do you have a reason for that?
How can I create key pairs without using this interface?
How can I bring back the feature to create key pair from that interface?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have more than two key pairs available for use at any one point in time, see [Access Credential Rotation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#CredentialRotation):

> [...] you can have two credentials in an Active state at any point in time
>   so you can rotate them without impact to your application's
>   availability. The AWS Security Credentials page displays the current
>   state of each of the credentials you can rotate. The possible states:
>
> - Active—Can be used to secure requests to AWS.
> - Inactive—Can't be used, but can be moved back to the Active state.
> - Deleted—Can never be used again.

The first sentence is actually a bit misleading, insofar it applies to key pairs in the *Inactive* state as well, because these can be activated again.

As soon as you delete an inactive key, you will be able to create a new one.